# drag and drop of images using opengl c++

Tags: c++, image, opengl, mousemove

i want to create a game similare to this one http://www.sciencekids.co.nz/gamesactivities/movinggrowing.html

1-how to move the image according to coordinates from the mouse? i know how to translate an object that i drow like polygon but not images?

2- how to check if its in right plce and make it stuck there
i used gltranslate but the image didn't move , and tried copypixl but it kept copying the image
every where the mouse hits .

```
 #include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <gl/glaux.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"glaux.lib")

AUX_RGBImageRec *image ;
GLsizei wh = 600, ww = 800;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void display(void){

    image = new AUX_RGBImageRec();
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    image = auxDIBImageLoad(L"boy.bmp");
    glDrawPixels(image->sizeX, image->sizeY, GL_RGB,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,image->data);

    glFlush();
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void mouse (int btn , int state , int x , int y){

    int h = wh-y ;
    if(btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN){

        /*glPushMatrix();*/
        /*glTranslatef(x , h , 0);*/
        glRasterPos2i(x,h);
        glCopyPixels(0,0,image->sizeX, image->sizeY,GL_COLOR);
        //glPopMatrix();}
        if(btn == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP) {

          // check if it is in right place to stuck it else will retuen to original place  
      }
    }glFlush();

}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void intiate(){

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluOrtho2D(0,ww,0,wh);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main()
{
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGB);  
glutInitWindowSize (ww, wh);
glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
glutCreateWindow ("Inside my Body");
intiate();
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288861/mouse-drag-object-in-opengl-glut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1-how to move the image according to coordinates from the mouse? i know how to translate an object that i drow like polygon but not images?

First and foremost: Please don't use glDrawPixels. Use textures instead, applied to regular geometry. OpenGL doesn't deal with user input, so you'll have to implement the mouse interaction yourself. **Never** place OpenGL drawing commands in the input event handler. In the input event handler, change some variables, set flags, etc. but don't draw. With the flags set, issue a redraw so that you can draw the updates.

> 2- how to check if its in right plce and make it stuck there

OpenGL is a drawing API, not a scene graph. You tell it what to draw and that's it. If things are not looking like you're expecting them, then you're not drawing them right.

Pro-Tip: Place all OpenGL commands in the drawing routine. Do not call any OpenGL functions from anywhere else. The stuff you do in your `initiate` function actually belongs in the display function.